# Pc won't start after new ram

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I have 4 GB RAM (2x2) and I just bought 4 GB Kingston (the old and the new are both Kingston same frequency). I put new RAM into the slot but the PC don't start. I reset BIOS and removed the BIOS battery. This is a pre-built PC. Is there a chance that the serial numbers of the old RAM memory to be bound in BIOS?
Software/Hardware used: old ram kingston kvr 1333mhz d3n9/2 , new ram hyper x hx313c9/4

Comment: No, there is no chance of this.

Comment: So you have 2+2 and you are trying to add a single 4GB stick?  You might not be able to do that.

How about some more system details. what kind of pre-built PC is it?

Comment: If the motherboard is built to use interleaved RAM, it'll require two identical sticks in each slot pair (this is done to speed up RAM access).  It's also possible that an older MB may not accept 4 GB in a single socket due to RAM total limitations in the BIOS (or might accept a single 4GB stick only in certain sockets).  Try starting with only the new RAM in socket 0 -- if that works, you *may* be able to add back the old RAM in slots 2 and 3, but more likely you'll need another 4x1 stick to get 8 GB total.

Comment: Have you tried only the new ram to make sure the new ram is not a DoA (Dead on Arrival) Its possible both ram sticks are somehow incompatible, its possible the new ram is defective, or the new ram is somehow not compatible with your system. If the new ram alone does not work on your system, you can try it on another system, but you are likely to return it to get a new one (or refund, depending on their policy)

Comment: main board msi g41m p26 (ms-7592)   cpu intel e5700  dual core,  ram ddr3 dual 4 gb , video  adm hd 5500. is not Doa 99% sure , first time i bought  8gb (8x1) and it didn/t work  i thought is from the main board ( it accepts 8 gb ram max but it doesnt say if it must be 4x2 or 8x1) so i return and take a smaller 4x1  ram  this time I'm pretty sure is my pc's fault.

Comment: First test the new stick alone to make sure it's compatible with your system. Then make sure the two old sticks are on the same channel, not in their original slots, when you add the new stick. Also, it would be helpful to know what motherboard you have.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases you should be able to install 3 module at the same time (2*2 + 4), frequency doesn't matter. The only question is bitness of the memory banks (capacity) that are composed from these modules with respect to the chipset settings. And memory banks, in turn, depend on the number of chips that you have on the module.

According to specs:
Kingston KVR1333D3N9/2G has 16 chips on each, i.e. 256M x 64-bit (2GB)
DDR3-1333 2Rx8 memory module, based on sixteen 128M x 8-bit DDR3-1333 FBGA components.
Your new HyperX HX313C9FR/4 is a 512M x 64-bit (4GB) DDR3-1333 1Rx8 memory module, based on eight 512M x 8-bit DDR3 FBGA components.

hence, the number of banks is different. You'll need to test a new module separately (alone) to verify if its 512M chips are at least compatible with your chipset. If it will work - that means that your chipset can't works with old and new modules at the same time. If it won't - you'll need to find some 16-chip 4GB module for your system.

Specs:

- http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3N9_2G.pdf
- http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX313C9FR_4.pdf